# Installation failed when starting an app in android studio using ndk?

Tags: android-studio, opencv, android-ndk

I am creating new project with opencv and these are the steps that i am applying to run opencv in my app.

New project and importing opencv module.

setting opencv targetsdk  and min sdk with module app gradle files.

creating new jni folder and adding jni libraries from open sdk.

As deprecatedndk=true is not working properly

it gives error c++ files should be set with ndk or cmake so for that

i link c++ with gradle on app folder.

this shows pop up of  linking with whether Ndk or Cmake.

i choose ndk and give path of

```
D:\opencv-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\Opencv.mk
```

there are 2 issues also occurs after that

```
import org.opencv.R and import.opencv.BuildConfig are not found
```

these imports are showing under opencv1 so,

```
import org.opencv1.R and import.opencv1.Buildconfig
```

after that it is successfully getting build but on running the app installation failed with message

```
Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

when clicking ok

```
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.inpaintapp2"
Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.example.inpaintapp2
Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: com.example.inpaintapp2
at com.android.server.pm.Settings.isOrphaned(Settings.java:4400)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:21529)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackageVersioned(PackageManagerService.java:18603)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:913)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:912)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:134)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:96)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21828)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:573)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:473)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2644)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3486)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
Error while Installing APK
```

on cancel

```
Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
Error while Installing APK
```

Comment: fix code blocks

Comment: Well, the error is that there isn't enough space to install the app where you want it to be installed. So you could either remove the internalOnly requirement or free up some space on the device. Another thing to consider is that debuggable versions of native libraries sometime can get quite large, so if you're builing in debug mode, try building in release mode instead just to see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: the issue was with emulator pixel l ,  after wiping  i deleted emulator  and then started the emulator  again it resolved my error.